# How to set multiple ranges for `yticks` on a single plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to set two different limits in my plot but i am not getting any success.
For a single range I know i can use simply `plt.yticks(min_range,max_range,step=x)`, this will give me a plot with x difference between each tick, But what i want is,`plt.yticks((0,2,step=0.1),(2,max_range,step=2)),` So That On my plot i want to have ticks of difference 0.1 between 0 and 2 and after that the step size of 2.
Any Help on this Please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate such customized tick values using two arrays with different spacing. You can then merge them (`concatenate`) to get a single array and then assign them to `plt.yticks()`. Although the output on the y-axis is hard to read but that's for you to sort out how to make it more readable. Below is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 7, 100)
y = x
tick1 = np.arange(0,2, 0.1)

tick2 = np.arange(2, 8, 2)
yticks = np.concatenate((tick1, tick2))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks(yticks);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much, though didn't look like what I was expecting, but will work for me :)

Comment: @Rizwan: Instead of 0.1, you can use 0.2 spacing to make it look better

Comment: I did :)... And  i am using tick of 0.5, and for upper limit i increased the tick difference.
Anything lower than 0.3 was not understandable... Thanks :)